# MongoDB aggregation sort by multiple fields

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

This is my data:

```
{
   "name": "some name",
   "blockNumber": 10,
   "uniqueId: 2
},
{
   "name": "some name",
   "blockNumber": 9,
   "uniqueId: 3
},
{
   "name": "some name",
   "blockNumber": 10,
   "uniqueId: 1
},
```

This is my query:

```
myModel.aggregate([
        {
          $match: someFilter,
        },
        {
          $sort: { blockNumber: -1 },
        },
])
```

And there is the expected result:

```
{
   "name": "some name",
   "blockNumber": 10,
   "uniqueId: 1
},
{
   "name": "some name",
   "blockNumber": 10,
   "uniqueId: 2
},
{
   "name": "some name",
   "blockNumber": 9,
   "uniqueId: 3
}
```

I am looking for a way to additionally sort the data depending on a second value (in this case uniqueId) only if blockNum is the same for multiple documents, so that the final result is also sorted by descending uniqueId. Example:

```
{
   "name": "some name",
   "blockNumber": 10,
   "uniqueId: 2
},
{
   "name": "some name",
   "blockNumber": 10,
   "uniqueId: 1
},
{
   "name": "some name",
   "blockNumber": 9,
   "uniqueId: 3
}
```

Comment: The final result is incorrect. You mentioned sort by `blockNumber` descending and `uniqueId` ascending, the document with `blockNumber: 10` and `uniqueId: 1` will come first then followed by `blockNumber: 10` and `uniqueId: 2`.

Comment: you can add more than one field to `$sort` stage [check this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/73Hi5rzTduy)

Comment: @1sina1 If I add another sort stage the final result will be sorted by uniqueId files, or I am wrong?

Comment: [docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/). if you use two sort stage it will get sort by the last one. if you use multiple fields on one `$sort` documents are first sorted by <field1>. Then documents with the same <field1> values are further sorted by <field2>.

Answer (score 2):

I actually figured it out: just add a second field to the sort stage.
The query is:

```
myModel.aggregate([
        {
          $match: someFilter,
        },
        {
          $sort: { blockNumber: -1, uniqueId: -1 },
        },
])
```

The result:

```
{
   "name": "some name",
   "blockNumber": 10,
   "uniqueId": 2
},
{
   "name": "some name",
   "blockNumber": 10,
   "uniqueId": 1
},
{
   "name": "some name",
   "blockNumber": 9,
   "uniqueId": 3
}
```

Comment: would you mind, providing an example in your response? That way anyone googling this, has an example on how to do it

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

```
.sort({ $natural: 1 })
```